# Angular 7.0.3 cli - Dynamically load external module from webpack bundle

Tags: angular, webpack, dynamic, angular-cli, bundle

I have two Angular 7.0.3 cli apps. When I navigate to a certain route, I would like to get the second app as an external webpack bundle from a proxy server and mount it on my main application.

Specifically I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I need to set up my angular.json and/or custom webpack.config file (if i need one at all) so that I have a single bundle that I can serve up. Additionally, I'm not quite sure how to handle my CustomModuleLoader.load() function.

Some background:

I am using APP_INITIALIZER to get a config that holds data on what routes need to be dynamically added. I reset the config with the new values. Lets say my second app is handling a clients page:

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (myCustomServiceFactory: SomeService) => () => myCustomServiceFactory.get(), deps: [SomeService], multi: true },
```

Service:

```
    get() {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
            .toPromise()
            .then((body: DataApiResponseMessage) => {
                let router = this.injector.get(Router);
                let routeArray: Route[] = [];
                //example route
                let route: Route = {
                    path: 'clients',
                    loadChildren: '@myapp/clients#ClientsModule'
                };
                routeArray.push(route);
                router.resetConfig([...routeArray, ...router.config]); 
            })
            .catch((error) => this.handleError(error))
    }
```

When '/clients' is navigated to I ask for the external bundle from my second app:

```
app.use('/@myapp/clients', function (req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:3001' });
});
```

My second app responds with dist/main.js

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist/main.js'));
```

My CustomModuleLoader:

```
import { Injectable, Injector, Compiler, NgModuleFactoryLoader, 
NgModuleFactory } from '@angular/core';

const SEPARATOR = '#';

@Injectable()
    export class CustomModuleLoader implements NgModuleFactoryLoader {
    constructor(private compiler: Compiler, private injector: Injector) {

    }

    load(path: string): Promise<NgModuleFactory<any>> {
        let [url, moduleName] = path.split(SEPARATOR);

        return this.loadScript(url).then(() => {
            //build and return ngModuleFactory here from
            //@myapp/clients bundle.js file or window (?)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    loadScript(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            script.src = url;
            script.charset = "UTF-8";
            script.onload = function () {
                resolve();
            }
            script.onerror = function () {
                reject();
            }
            body.appendChild(script);
        });
    }
}
```

In my second app I'm using `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` and declaring `customWebpackConfig`. I have (an empty because I'm not quite sure what to put in there) `webpack.config.js` file where I would declare angular and other major libraries as external and output a single bundle.js file.

What angular.json / webpack.config.js confiurgation do I need to correctly serve up my second application ? How then do I handle mounting the webpack bundle as an ngModule in my main app inside my CustomModuleLoader.load() function?

Comment: Split  one app into two module(two 'app' ) will be simpler，or you can use Mona https://github.com/phodal/mooa